# Estimate the decrease in the period of the satellite to the nearest one-hundredth hour....

Tags: calculus

According to Kepler's Third Law, the period T (in days) of a satellite moving in a circular orbit x mi above the surface of the earth is given by $T=.0588(1+\frac{x}{3959})^{\frac{3}{2}}$ Suppose that a communications satellite is moving in a circular orbit 28,000 mi above the earth's surface. Because of friction, the satellite drops down to a new orbit 27,500 mi above the earth's surface. Estimate the decrease in the period of the satellite to the nearest one-hundredth hour.

So this is what I think I have, not sure whether I'm right or wrong. $ΔT=T'dx$ So $dx=-500$ and $T'=.0588(\frac{3}{2}(1+\frac{x}{3959})^{.5}*\frac{1}{3959}$ So $T'(28,000)=.000063298$ and then I multiply $.000063298(-500)=-.03(rounded)$ but it's wrong and I suppose I'm approaching the problem wrong. A precise step by step solution would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to convert $T$ into hours. So $0.3$ days reduction means $7.2$ hours. Is that closer to the real answer?

Comment: @Arthur Yes solved my problem, thanks. And the as I mentioned in the other answer, I'm getting graded for the process. So the answer might be worth 1/10 total points if I don't show the process the professor want me to show. So, I am just preparing for that. Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

Could you just sub in T(28000) - T(27500)?
Edit: After a quick read of linear approximation, it looks like what you're doing is right. Did you check your units though?

Comment: You mean T(28000) -T(27,500)? If so, I have to do it the calculus way. Which is what I'll be tested on...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure but is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: What would be the calculus way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. But on exams I have to do it the "calculus" way as stated before. Ex. Last exam I had a question that asked for the $\sqrt{3.9}$ which I could've easily plugged into my calculator and wrote down the answer, but that would've got me the whole question marked wrong. I had to do linearization, so I need to learn how to do this the "calculus" way.

Comment: I'm not sure... That's why I asked the question..

Comment: Oh right, my bad..

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your answer?

Comment: Yeah, I solved the problem. I made a silly reading mistake. Thanks.